# HTML button call on javascript function not working with sqlite database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sqlite

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>SqliteSampleForm</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sample Sqlite Database Form</h1>
        <p align="center">

            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstname" />
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastname" />
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter contact number" name="contactnumber" /> <br /><br />

       <button onclick="add()"> submit </button>   

        </p>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>


    </body >
</html >
```

Here's my index.js file:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var db = null;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "note.db", iosDatabaseLocation: 'default' });
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS note (firstname text primary key, lastname text, contactnumber text)");
        alert("Database Table created");
    }, function (err) {
        alert("An error occured while initializing the app");
    });
}, false);

function add() {
    alert("Inside Add Function");
    var firstname = document.getElementByName("firstname").value;
    alert("Variabe firstname created: " + firstname);
    var lastname = document.getElementByName("lastname").value;
    var contactnumber = document.getElementsByName("contactnumber").value;

    if (firstname == "") {
        alert("Please enter first name");
        return;
    }

    if (lastname == "") {
        alert("Please enter last name");
        return;
    }


    if (contactnumber == "") {
        alert("Please enter contact number");
        return;
    }

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO note (firstname, lastname, contactnumber) VALUES (?,?,?)", [firstname, lastname, contactnumber], function (tx, res) {
            alert("Fields Added to the database");
        });
    }, function (err) {
        alert("An error occurred while saving the note");
    });
}
} )();
```

and the css file may not be needed so to avoid too much code i would avoid it.

On clicking submit button, i should get the alert that i am inside add function as stated in the function definition, but i am not getting it.
Where as i am getting the Database created alert in my application.
Is this error due to sqlite database in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying i figured out than if there's an error in your javascript file (syntax error or any other) the java script file doesn't load.

on removing the error you will be able to run the script as required